# sanction: a dead easy OAuth2 client Python implementation

Tags: library, python, oauth2

## Overview

sanction is a lightweight, dead simple (**67 LOC!**) client implementation of the OAuth2 protocol. The major goals of the library are:

- Support multiple providers

  - Most providers have varying levels of diversion from the official spec. The goal with this library is to either handle these diversions natively, or expose a method to allow client code to deal with it efficiently and effectively.
- Support all server-side OAuth2 flows

  - Three of the four OAuth2 flows should be supported by this library. Currently, only authorization code and client credential flows have been tested due to lack of other (known) implementations.

## Example

```
c = Client(token_endpoint="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    resource_endpoint="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1",
    redirect_uri="http://localhost:8080/login/google",
    client_id=config["google.client_id"],
    client_secret=config["google.client_secret"])

# redirect user to authorization page
my_redirect(client.flow.authorization_uri(state=my_state))

# get access token and make a resource request
c.request_token(response_dict)
c.request("/userinfo")
```

## Supported Providers

The following OAuth2 providers have been (lightly) tested:

- Facebook (include the test API)
- Google
- Foursquare
- bitly
- GitHub
- StackExchange
- Instagram

There is sample code for each in the example directory.

*I decided to re-post this package as not only did the github repo URI change, but it underwent a ridiculously large refactor, going from roughly 470 LOC to 67 (looking nothing like the original)*

https://github.com/demianbrecht/sanction

Comment: No link to the project :) ?

Comment: @systempuntoout: Eesh. Feeling a little sheepish now.. Added :)

Comment: This is promising: can it replace all that facepy, flickrapi or oauth2client altogether? (y)